# What's wrong with this code? Returns duplicate result of the last item

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

With the code below, the last item ($term->name) returns duplicate entries of the last item.

Output:

Example: Computing, Fashion, Publication, Medicine, Medicine

Example: IT, Music, Technology, Techonology

Help!

```
<?php $vocabularies = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
    foreach($vocabularies as $vocabulary) {
       if ($vocabularies) {
          $terms = taxonomy_node_get_terms_by_vocabulary($node, $vocabulary->vid);
             if ($terms) {
       $i = 1;
       $len = count($terms);
                foreach ($terms as $term) {                     
             if ($i == 1) {
                   print '<span class="separator">' . t($term->name) . '</span>' . ' , '; }
                 else {
                    print '<span class="separator">' . t($term->name) . '</span>' . ' , '; }
             if ($i == $len) {
                   print '<span class="separator">' . t($term->name) . '</span>'; }
        $i++;
                }
              }
       }
    } ?>
```

Comment: what's the point of the `if ($vocabularies)` test? That could never be reached if $vocabularies WASN'T a non-empty array anyways, so you're basically doing `if (true == true)`. Perhaps that line and the first foreach should be swapped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($i == 1) {
    // the first element
} else {
    // other elements, including the last one
}

if ($i == $len) {
    // the last element again
}
```

You might want to change that to:

```
if ($i == 1) {
    // the first element
} else if ($i < $len) {
    // other elements, excluding the last one
}

if ($i == $len) {
    // the last element
}
```

or, if the first element has no special significance:

```
if ($i < $len) {
    // all elements excluding the last one
} else {
    // the last element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `else-if` for the last conditional. Now you are essentially checking each element with 2 ifs:

```
If i is one, do this, else that.
AND
If i is the last one, also do this
```